Не отображается картинка в Springboot через Thymeleaf
Не отображает картинку в SpringBoot с использованием Thymeleaf.
Пробовал вставлять ссылки из интернета, работает. Но если вставляю путь с жеского диска, то нет. Вот код:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css" data-th-href="@{css/style.css}" >
</head>
<body>
<img th:src="@{img/OIG4.jpg}">
</body>
</html>


Боже, как же все было просто. Надо было поместить файл в папку resources/static/img. Потерял на это пол дня.
